# mysql trouble with 2 inner join paths referencing the same end location

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm new to mysql and having trouble with 2 join paths, 4 inner joins in total.

both join paths go threw different middle tables but reference the same finish locations.

first path

`stockitem.dep_id -> dep.dep_id and dep.city_id -> city.city_id`

second path

`stockitem.manu_id -> manufacturer.manu_id and manufacturer.city_id -> city.city_id`

with the final column being referenced by both city.city_name

here is what I've written for it:

```
SELECT
stockitem.stk_id as 'STOCK ID', 
stockitem.stk_name as 'STOCK NAME', 
city.city_name as 'MANUFACTURER CITY', 
city.city_name as 'DEPOT CITY'
FROM stockitem
JOIN manufacturer
    ON stockitem.manu_id = manufacturer.manu_id
JOIN city
    ON manufacturer.city_id = city.city_id
AND
JOIN depot
    ON stockitem.dep_id = depot.dep_id
JOIN city
    ON depot.city_id = city.city_id;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the query?

Comment: it is return this error--


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN depot ON stockitem.dep_id = depot.dep_id JOIN city ON depot.city_id' at line 12--


line 12 is the start of the join depot

Comment: It's because of the `AND`, just take it out.

Comment: ok now its returning an error, #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'city'.
i kind of get why its asking for alias's for city table but they both reference the same location.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is due to the placement of `AND` between the `JOIN`'s so I've removed it. The second error is because you are `JOIN`ing `city` twice (which would require an alias on one of the join's).

```
SELECT
stockitem.stk_id as 'STOCK ID', 
stockitem.stk_name as 'STOCK NAME', 
city.city_name as 'MANUFACTURER CITY', 
city.city_name as 'DEPOT CITY'
FROM stockitem
JOIN manufacturer
    ON stockitem.manu_id = manufacturer.manu_id
JOIN city
    ON manufacturer.city_id = city.city_id
JOIN depot
    ON stockitem.dep_id = depot.dep_id;
JOIN city as c2
    ON depot.city_id = c2.city_id
```